# Price rule based on number of extra product varieties

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules, rules

Is it possible to make a rule that checks if there is more than one variety of a specific product in the cart, based on the custom options?

It should then apply a $10 discount for each additional product line

For example:

- Product A - red
- Product A - blue
- Product A - purple
- Product B
- Product C

Should = $20 discount.

Comment: discount apply only based on the custom options product or configurable options product also?

Comment: All of my products are simple products, so the variety would be based on custom options. Whenever there is a new product line in the cart with the same product name.

Comment: okay got. Need to customization in core file Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator for the your requirement